# using Custom Error Page in IIS7.5

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I have configured a site to use SSL, thus I added following section in my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors>
            <error statusCode="403" subStatusCode="4" path="D:\Data\www\Site\403.htm" responseMode="File" />
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Once I have included it, and when I visited http://my-url/pagr/some.aspx I got `The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.` message. If I remove it I could see default 403 error page.

Is it something wrong with my config?

Comment: Are you sure `D:\Data\wwwroot\Site\403.htm` exists on the live server?

Comment: @Curt, I am pretty sure, because I used II7 management console to pick the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset IIS to check if the path you set works

or

Give relative path from your website root instead of give the file system path to check if it works

Put the 403.htm in the same folder your web.config is located.

```
<error statusCode="403" subStatusCode="4" path="403.htm" responseMode="File" />
```

Comment: In this case the default 403 page is displayed.

Comment: Did you reset IIS after setting httpError tags

Comment: I did a reset and got same result.